# Code First vs Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я почти не имею опыта c EF и собираюсь начать новый проект. Стою перед выбором с чего начать создание доменнной модели с базы или с кода.

В чем преимущества каджого из этих подходов и есть ли они вообще или это вопрос вкуса?

Comment: ну в одном случае EF за вас делает таблицы, в другом EF за вас делает классы, что удобней то и выбирайте

Comment: если не ошибаюсь в последней версии EF убрали возможность Database First

Comment: В своё время обсуждалось на sql.ru: http://www.sql.ru/forum/1157560-1/pokritikuyte-ef-code-first

Comment: В новых проектах я бы рекомендовал с CF начинать.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

диаграмма ниже поможет выбрать подход:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хороший ресурс для тех кто только начинает изучать EF: [Руководство по Entity Framework](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще конечно полезно все знать как работает, но конкретно с EF "джедаем" быть не обязательно, создавать модель проще и нагляднее, хотя на вкус и цвет как говорится. Вот сатья где очень подробно это разбирается [2 часть](http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc3-in-depth-entity-framework-02-working-with-entity-framework).